# How to export Test case with Test Steps from Rally?

Tags: rally

Consider Test cases in `Rally` contains multiple steps under steps section. Each step has input and expected result. I want to view and export all details of test cases (including Steps). 
While creating view for test steps which field is mapped as only validation input and validation expected result fields can be accessed. Unable to find fields for steps input and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

`TestCaseStep` is a separate entity from the `TestCase` itself so it appears as a child collection to `TestCase` named `Steps`. Rally doesn't automatically fetch the fields of child collection entities when you say fetch=true, but you can explicitly call for them. So you can say...

```
fetch=FormattedID,Steps,Input,ExpectedResult
```

If you embed that clause in a query like [this](https://demo.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/testcase.js?workspace=https://demo.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/workspace/729424&query=&fetch=FormattedID,Steps,Input,ExpectedResult&start=1&pagesize=20), you will get back results that look like this...

```
Results: [
  {
    _rallyAPIMajor: "1"
    ...
    _refObjectName: "Updated Totals"
    FormattedID: "TC1"
    Steps: [
      {
        ...
        ExpectedResult: "first step expected result"
        Input: "fist step input"
        _type: "TestCaseStep"
      },
      {
        ...
        ExpectedResult: "2nd step er"
        Input: "2nd step input"
        _type: "TestCaseStep"
      }
    ]
    _type: "TestCase"
  },
  ...
]
```